# Attach pdf from dynamic url

Tags: attachments, email, wp-mail, pdf

When I save a custom post, I would like to send a PDF by email as attachment.

I tried that :

```
function my_custom_save_post( $post_id, $post, $update )  {

    if( ! $update ) { return; }
    if( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) { return; }
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) and DOING_AUTOSAVE ) { return; }
    if( $post->post_type != 'MYCUSTOMPOST' ) { return; }
$url = wp_nonce_url( admin_url( "myCustomUrl" ), 'my_nounce_name' );
    $url = file_get_contents($url);
    $attachments = array( $url );
    $headers = 'From: My Name <wordpress@website.fr>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail( 'test@email.com', 'subject', $url, $headers, $attachments );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_custom_save_post', 10, 3 );
```

"myCustomUrl" not ending by .pdf

At first I started not to put `$url = file_get_contents($url);` and I received an email with the written URl (thanks to `$url` in `wp_mail()`) but without the file. URL works, if I open the link, I can see my file.
With `$url = file_get_contents($url);` I don't get an email

How to do this please ?

Comment: You need to use a file path within the server filesystem as an `$attachments` array item value, not the URL.

Comment: Okay thanks. But do you know how to save my file on the server filesystem thanks to URL

Comment: You don't know how to upload some file to the server? It can be uploaded like any other theme/plugin/etc file via FTP or you can use a media library to upload it.

Comment: I don't know how to do this with PHP, without user's action

Comment: I don't understand what `$url = wp_nonce_url( admin_url( "myCustomUrl" ), 'my_nounce_name' );` line should do and what is your `"myCustomUrl"` does mean. Where are your PDF file located?

Comment: i use a plugin that generates a pdf when you arrive on an url. "$url = wp_nonce_url( admin_url( "myCustomUrl" ), 'my_nounce_name' );"is the way I get the URL from the file I need. If I copy/glue this url, my pdf is displayed. "mycustomurl" is the URL allowing to generate the pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can try to do it in two ways.

The first one, much more simple, is to save a temporary PDF file somewhere, for example in a `uploads` directory, use it as attachment and delete if after the call to `wp_mail()` function is made:

```php
function my_custom_save_post( $post_id, $post, $update )  {
    if( ! $update ) { return; }
    if( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) { return; }
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) and DOING_AUTOSAVE ) { return; }
    if( $post->post_type != 'MYCUSTOMPOST' ) { return; }
    $url = wp_nonce_url( admin_url( "myCustomUrl" ), 'my_nounce_name' );
    $contents = file_get_contents( $url );
    # here temporary file name is a fixed string
    # but it better to be some unique string
    # (use current timestamp, post ID, etc)
    $tempfile = ABSPATH . 'uploads/filename.pdf';
    file_put_contents( $tempfile, $contents );
    $attachments = array( $tempfile );
    $headers = 'From: My Name <wordpress@website.fr>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail( 'test@email.com', 'subject', $url, $headers, $attachments );
    unlink( $tempfile );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_custom_save_post', 10, 3 );
```

The second is just a guess and needs to be tested. WordPress rely on [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) component for sending emails. That component has a [`addStringAttachment`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment) method which allows to attach a binary object assigned to a PHP variable as a email file attachment. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753122/phpmailer-addstringattachment-with-pdf) is the question about this topic. I don't see any way this could be used via `wp_mail()` function but in theory you can try to do it via `phpmailer_init` hook:

```php
function my_attach_pdf( $mailer_instance ) {
    $url = wp_nonce_url( admin_url( "myCustomUrl" ), 'my_nounce_name' );
    $contents = file_get_contents( $url );
    $mailer_instance->addStringAttachment( $contents, 'your_file_name.pdf' );
}
function my_custom_save_post( $post_id, $post, $update )  {
    if( ! $update ) { return; }
    if( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) { return; }
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) and DOING_AUTOSAVE ) { return; }
    if( $post->post_type != 'MYCUSTOMPOST' ) { return; }
    $headers = 'From: My Name <wordpress@website.fr>' . "\r\n";
    add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_attach_pdf' );
    wp_mail( 'test@email.com', 'subject', $url, $headers, $attachments );
    remove_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_attach_pdf' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_custom_save_post', 10, 3 );
```

I'm really curious if the second approach would work. Maybe give it a test one day. If you test it, please give some feedback.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I can confirm you that the second method works like a charm!

Comment: @MattiaMerlini I thought it should work, anyway thanks for testing and for the feedback! Appreciate!